# c++ [Error] no match for call to '(Lion) (int&, int&, int, int)'

Tags: c++

Given the following code :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;
int ch[25][25];

class State{
    public:
        int x;
        int y;
        int dis;
        State(int x, int y, int dis){
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
            this->dis = dis;
        }
        bool operator<(const State &s) const{
            if(this->dis == s.dis){
                if(this->y == s.y){
                    return this->x > x; 
                }
                else return this->y < s.y; 
            }
            else return this->dis > s.dis; 
        }
};

class Lion{
    public:
        int x, y, size, ate;
        Lion(){
            this->x = 0;
            this->y = 0;
            this->size = 2;
            this->ate = 0;
        }
        Lion(int x, int y, int size, int ate){
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
            this->size = 2;
            this->ate = 0;
        }
        
        void Sizeup(){
            size++;
            ate = 0;
            return ;
        }
        
};

int main() {
    
    int arr[25][25];
    int x[5] = {-1,0,1,0};
    int y[5] = {0,1,0,-1};
    int n,data,res;
    Lion simba;
    priority_queue<State> pq;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
            scanf("%d",&data);
            arr[i][j] = data;
            if(data == 9) {
                simba(i,j,2,0); // error
                arr[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    
    pq.push(State(simba.x,simba.y,0));
    
    while(!pq.empty()){
        State tmp = pq.top();
        int x1 = tmp.x;
        int y1 = tmp.y;
        
        if(arr[x1][y1]!=0 && arr[x1][y1]<simba.size){ 
            simba.x = x1;
            simba.y = y1;
            simba.ate++;
            if(simba.size == simba.ate) simba.Sizeup();
            arr[x1][y1] = 0; 
            
            for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){ 
                for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
                    ch[i][j] = 0;
                }
            } 
        }
        
        while(!pq.empty()) pq.pop();
        res = tmp.dis;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            int x2 = simba.x + x[i];
            int y2 = simba.y + y[i];
            if(x2>n || x2<1 || y2>n || y2<1 || arr[x2][y2] > simba.size || ch[x2][y2] > 0) continue;
            pq.push(State(x2,y2,tmp.dis+1)); 
            ch[x2][y2] = 0;
        }
        
        printf("%d",res);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

`simba(i,j,2,0);`
This is the part where the error occurred.

> [Error] no match for call to '(Lion) (int&, int&, int, int)'

Why am I getting this error?

Is there a difference between a variable declared in a `for` loop and a general variable as a parameter?

I want to know how to solve it.

Comment: I don't understand what you want the erroneous line of code to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean to reassign `simba` instead of calling it as a function? (poor Simba )

```
simba = Lion(i,j,2,0);
```

Comment: umm.. sorry I'm not sure understand. I want to intialize simba. (simba's maybe happy :) )

Comment: `simba(i,j,2,0)` tries to call `simba` as a function. That will only work if a) there is actually a function named `simba`, or b) you have implement the proper `operator()` overload in the `Lion` class. My answer shows how to reinitialize `simba` from a `Lion` object.

Comment: You can only *initialize* local variables at the point where they are declared. Otherwise you are assigning to them. But I'm not sure I understand how you expect the loop to work. Every time through, you set new values for your `Lion`... and then don't *do anything with it*, until *after* the loop. When `pq.push(State(simba.x,simba.y,0));`, it will use the values from the *last* iteration, and there is no way to see the other values. Was this your goal? To *find* a unique `9` in the user input, and have `simba`'s position correspond to when that is input?